# Laravel Composer error Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in Container.php:738

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have a problem that when I use command composer require st. or php artisan st. etc. I get this error:

> Using version ^2.3 for intervention/image ./composer.json has been
> updated
>
> > php artisan clear-compiled
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:738
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(738):
>
> ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
>
> ## 1 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(633):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
>
> ## 2 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
>
> ## 3 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(853):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
>
> ## 4 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(808):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
>
> ## 5 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(777):
>
> Il in
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
> on line 738 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log
> does not exist in
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:738
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(738):
>
> ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
>
> ## 1 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(633):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
>
> ## 2 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
>
> ## 3 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(853):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
>
> ## 4 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(808):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
>
> ## 5 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(777):
>
> Il in
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
> on line 738 Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the
> pre-update-cmd event returned with an error
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
> content.
>
> [RuntimeException]   Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:738
> Stack trace:   #0
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(738):
> ReflectionClass->__construct('log')   #1
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(633):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)   #2
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)   #3
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(853):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')   #4
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(808):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
>
> ## 5 D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(777):
>
> Il in
> D:\Programy\Wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
> on line 738
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-plugins]
> [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev]
> [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
> [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
> [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [].. .

I tried to reinstall composer, install the new version of PHP (7), but still nothing changed :( Do sb. know how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured this problem out. Package tinymce was cousing this. To fix it, replace 'cdn' => url('vendor/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'), by 
'cdn' => Config('app.url').'/vendor/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js', in **config/tinymce.php**.